# $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] empty for some users

Tags: php, spoofing, server-variables

I have activated

```
HostnameLookups Double
```

in my Apache2 configuration, so that I can store user's remote hosts and rest assured that their IP addresses are real and not spoofed.

However, I noticed that for quite a few of my 'users' (people entering a form), the $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] is just empty (while for most others it is nonempty), despite the above configuration. Does this mean that these users have spoofed IP adresses, or could these still be honest and regular users? What else could explain this?

Comment: How about using remote_addr?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not every host has a host name :)

You probably wanted to use `'REMOTE_ADDR'`

Comment: use `$REMOTE_HOST=$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] ?? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` or `gethostbyaddr($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"])`

Answer (score 3):

Quote from Apache documentation:

> The value Double refers to doing double-reverse DNS lookup. That is,
>   after a reverse lookup is performed, a forward lookup is then
>   performed on that result. At least one of the IP addresses in the
>   forward lookup must match the original address. (In "tcpwrappers"
>   terminology this is called PARANOID.)

I suspect that if the forward lookup doesn't match then the field is left empty.

As @avnr said, there's not always a PTR record for an IP address.

And in any case that doesn't ensure the IP is not spoofed, it just ensures that the DNS configuration of the original IP has a PTR and a A record matching.

Comment: Hmm... how would I ensure that the IP is not spoofed then? I'm already on https if it matters.

Comment: You can't ensure an IP is real. Usually an attacker will spoof to avoid being DOSed by your server answers, or it may spoof to an IP to make a DOS to this IP with the help of your server (along others).

Comment: And for the case of a forum post, he may spoof to send a spam and come back with its real address (or proxyfied one) after to see the correct result of its 'spoofed' send.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'])){//check
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'];
}else{
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];//else assign the real IP
}
echo $ip;
```

Comment: The `REMOTE_HOST` server variable is used for IP/hostname validation, not for finding the IP address of the client.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> $ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'); instead of $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

```
 getenv() is used to get the value of an environment variable in PHP
 $_SERVER is an array contains server variables created by the web server.
```